# How JavaScript handles inheritance?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I came across [a tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-complete-mvc-website-with-expressjs--net-34168) which had given code for inheritance:

```
module.exports = function(db) {
    this.db = db;
};
module.exports.prototype = {
   extend: function(properties) {
      var Child = module.exports;
      Child.prototype = module.exports.prototype;
      for(var key in properties) {
        Child.prototype[key] = properties[key];
     }
    return Child;
 },
  setDB: function(db) {
     this.db = db;
 },
 collection: function() {
    if(this._collection) return this._collection;
    return this._collection = this.db.collection('fastdelivery-content');
  }
}
```

1. What is the need of `Child.prototype = module.exports.prototype;`? As Child is module.exports only, so it should have the same prototype. Then why are we doing this ?
2. We are overriding `module.exports.prototype` and we are using module.exports.prototype inside it. How does it work? Isn't this kind of circular dependency?

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense indeed. Where exactly did you find it, can you share a link? I would use none of these techniques.

Comment: The tutorial is really bad! Use a different one. You are completely right about (1).

Comment: I have updated the link. Please have a look.

Comment: Heh. The tutorial has unit tests that assert that new properties/methods are added to the new class... but it doesn't have any tests that will notice that the new class is the same as the old class, which they've just accidentally modified. Even though their controller extension unit test (which uses non-inheritance extension code that actually works) would notice this. It seems like the author might not understand reference/pointer semantics in JavaScript. (Unless I'm also misunderstanding something...)

Comment: @jermy Banks Yes, I can see this issue in comment section in that tutorial. May be the tutorial is not completely correct. But as I am new to nodejs I was thinking I am not getting it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: actually it works, because he's just doing `Child.prototype = Child.prototype` - a noop. But the authors comment "*The implementation of the extend `method` is a little bit tricky, because we have to change the prototype of module.exports, but still keep the original constructor.*" really suggests that he has no clue.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, that's a telling quote. I just meant that because the same `module.exports` is always used as the value for `Child`, it's not possible to create "children" with different properties.